# Difficulty processing form with IP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Having a difficulty involving a form that wants the user to fill in his/her IP.

Gives the following error;

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "'192.192.192.192/32'" LINE 1: ...ess, ip, status) VALUES ('1',
>   'TestFirstName', 'TestLastName' '192.192.1... ^ in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LoginHQ/functions.php on line 22

Apparentely, something is going wrong with the IP form field that gets sent through a POST.

My query is as following;

```
$result = pg_query($dbconnection, "INSERT INTO clients(clientid, firstname, lastname, ipaddress, ip, status) VALUES ('$clientid', '$FirstName', '$LastName' '$ip', '$status')");
```

Is there something wrong with this formatting, or should I dig deeper?

Comment: What is the data type of your `ip` column?

Comment: @juergend cidr datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma between `'$LastName'` and `'$ip'`.Correct your query like this

```
$result = pg_query($dbconnection, "INSERT INTO clients(clientid, firstname, lastname, ipaddress, ip, status) VALUES ('$clientid', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$ip', '$status')")
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes, thank you very much. Works perfect now. I guess the temporary broken coffee machine in here starts to have his effects...

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `,` between `'$LastName'` and `'$ip'`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma (,) between `'$LastName'` and `'$ip'`.